# How do I pass url path argument to view success url, in url patterns?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to pass the `<int:pk>` of my `view_submission` path to the `success_url`.  Can you please help?  I can't seem to find a way to do this here, without changing the code in my views file, which I'd really not like to do because I want to keep these all in the urls file.

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', 
     login_required(SubmissionsList.as_view()), 
     name='all_submissions'),
path('create',
     login_required(SubmissionCreate.as_view(
          success_url=reverse_lazy('all_submissions'))),
     name='create_submission'),
path('view/<int:pk>',
     login_required(SubmissionDetail.as_view()),
     name='view_submission'),
path('edit/<int:pk>',
     login_required(SubmissionUpdate.as_view(
          success_url=reverse_lazy('view_submission', kwargs={'pk': pk}))),
     name='edit_submission'),
path('delete/<int:pk>',
     login_required(SubmissionDelete.as_view(
          success_url=reverse_lazy('all_submissions'))),
     name='delete_submission'),
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this only with the `urls.py` file. Even if you get the parameter right in the `urls.py` file (hint: you can get more than one path pointing to the same view) you still must override `get_success_url` in your view in order to redirect the user to the right `<int:pk>`.

Comment: Right.  See, I feel like there should be a way to do this.  It seems a bit more elegant to be able to have all these in the same file, at least in this particular solution.  Just like I keep all my login_required in the same file.  This way I can just look at my urls.py and see what is login_required.  I'd like the same for my success urls.  I may have to give in and put them in my views though :)